# Finding $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{\log(n+1)} = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Can we use Sandwich theorem to show that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{\log(n+1)} = 0$$ I am not getting the proper estimate.

Please give a hint.

Comment: So, what did you try? :)

Comment: Do you mean, prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\log(n+1)}=0$?

Comment: why ? you simply have that $lim_{n\to \infty }\log(n+1)=+\infty $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $n\geq e^M$, $0>\log(n+1)>M$, hence: $$0<\frac{1}{\log(n+1)}<\frac{1}{M}.$$
Since $M$ is arbitrary, the limit is zero.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a result that might help you with other limits as well

If $(x_n)$ is a bounded sequence and $\lim y_n = +\infty$ then $\lim \frac{x_n}{y_n} = 0$

Proof: There exist $c > 0$ such that $|x_n|\leq c$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Now take any $\epsilon > 0$, then there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$n > n_0 \implies y_n > \frac{c}{\epsilon}$$

Then $$n> n_0 \implies \Big|\frac{x_n}{y_n}\Big| < c \ \dot \ \frac{\epsilon}{c} = \epsilon$$

Thus $\lim \frac{x_n}{y_n} = 0$.

Now take $(x_n) = 1$ and $y_n = \log (n + 1)$.

Answer (score 0):

may be useful $$\frac{1}{n+1}<\frac{1}{n} \\0<\frac{1}{log(n+1)}<\frac{1}{log(n)}\\n \to \infty \\n=10^{m} \\m \to +\infty  \\0<\frac{1}{log(10^{m}+1)}<\frac{1}{log(10^{m})}\\$$$$0<\frac{1}{log(10^{m}+1)}<\frac{1}{m}\\$$when $$m \to +\infty $$